# Find max since condition in pandas timeseries dataframe

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I'm trying to find the max since condition was true in a pandas dataframe.  I've searched for similar questions and read the documentation but haven't been able to find this problem discussed.  To illustrate, I want a function that will return the maxsince column below.

```
In [84]: df
Out[84]: 
                     a      b  maxsince
2007-04-27 11:00:00  1   True         1
2007-04-27 11:30:00  5  False         5
2007-04-27 12:00:00  3  False         5
2007-04-27 12:30:00  2   True         2
2007-04-27 13:00:00  2  False         2
2007-04-27 13:30:00  7   True         7
2007-04-27 14:00:00  3  False         7
2007-04-27 14:30:00  4  False         7
```

I'm having trouble calculating this without resorting to looping.  What would be the most efficient way?  Thanks.

Comment: Is df.groupby('b').max() what your looking for?

Comment: No, I'm looking for something like a cummax() that resets on each True in 'b'.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about:

```
>>> df.groupby(df["b"].cumsum())["a"].cummax()
2007-04-27  11:00:00    1
            11:30:00    5
            12:00:00    5
            12:30:00    2
            13:00:00    2
            13:30:00    7
            14:00:00    7
            14:30:00    7
dtype: int64
```

This works because

```
>>> df["b"].cumsum()
2007-04-27  11:00:00    1
            11:30:00    1
            12:00:00    1
            12:30:00    2
            13:00:00    2
            13:30:00    3
            14:00:00    3
            14:30:00    3
Name: b, dtype: int32
```

gives us a new value whenever we see a `True`.  You might have to patch it a bit depending on what you want to happen when the first value is `False`, but I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader. ;^)

Comment: Nice one. Cookbook worthy?

Comment: +1 I thought about doing this with pd.rolling_apply and then group, but this one is obviously better

Comment: What version of pandas are you using?  Version 0.12.0 gives me ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer when I try df["b"].cumsum().

Comment: Ah.  I'm using `'0.12.0-559-ga11e143'`.  You could simply do `df["b"].astype(int).cumsum()` or `(df["b"]*1).cumsum()` to get around that.  (I don't have 0.12 easily available, unfort., so it's possible you might have to make it a `float` too-- hard to guess.)

Comment: Ok, that got it working.  Thanks for the answer.  Wish I would've thought of that.